# Resizing a Charts UI Dashboard w/ Google Apps Script

Tags: user-interface, charts, google-apps-script, resize, dashboard

After creating a new Google Spreadsheet I've dropped the following code into the script editor so that it is bound to the Google Spreadsheet.

```
Function doGet() { var data = Charts.newDataTable()
  .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, "Name")
  .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, "Gender")
  .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, "Age")
  .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, "Donuts eaten")
  .addRow(["Michael", "Male", 12, 5])
  .addRow(["Michael", "Male", 12, 5])
  .addRow(["Elisa", "Female", 20, 7])
  .addRow(["Robert", "Male", 7, 3])
  .addRow(["John", "Male", 54, 2])
  .addRow(["Jessica", "Female", 22, 6])
  .addRow(["Aaron", "Male", 3, 1])
  .addRow(["Margareth", "Female", 42, 8])
  .addRow(["Miranda", "Female", 33, 6])
  .build();

var ageFilter = Charts.newNumberRangeFilter()
  .setFilterColumnLabel("Age")
  .build();

var genderFilter = Charts.newCategoryFilter()
  .setFilterColumnLabel("Gender")
  .build();

var pieChart = Charts.newPieChart()
  .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition()
                        .setColumns([0,3]))
  .build();

var tableChart = Charts.newTableChart()
  .build();

var dashboard = Charts.newDashboardPanel()
  .setDataTable(data)
  .bind([ageFilter, genderFilter], [pieChart, tableChart])
  .build();

var uiApp = UiApp.createApplication().setHeight(900).setWidth(900);

dashboard.add(uiApp.createVerticalPanel()
            .add(uiApp.createHorizontalPanel()
                .add(ageFilter).add(genderFilter)
                .setSpacing(70))
            .add(uiApp.createHorizontalPanel()
                .add(pieChart).add(tableChart)
                .setSpacing(10)));

uiApp.add(dashboard);

var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
spreadsheet.show(uiApp);
}
```

It's pretty much the same code as what's found on the Google Developer's Blog (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/charts_dashboard).

When this code is deployed as a web app where I access it by URL the charts and whatnot are easily in view. On the other hand, when I've tied the script to my Google Spreadsheet and run the script... it comes out relatively small so not all the charts are shown (same problem when I drop the web app into a google site using the script gadget). So basically, thoughts on how I can get around this? I know  I can dictate in the code the height and width of the uiInstance with .setwidth and .setheight but I'd like for the dashboard to be appropriate sized on load, capable of being resized by dragging a corner, or, as a last resort, capable of having scroll bars so that I can scroll to the rest of the charts... thoughts?